# C2DM server side C# web service Error=InvalidRegistration

Tags: c#, android, push, android-c2dm

I have searched everywhere and have not found an answer to my question. Let me get straight to the point. I have developed an android messaging app for the purpose of experimenting with C2DM. My app get's the registration ID and it gets displayed in my Log correctly. I then send that key through to my C# web service.

The C# Web service then applies for an auth token, which works fine. No problem so far. But, as soon as I POST my body items `(registration_id, collapse_key, data.<key>, delay_while_idle`) with my header`(GoogleLogin auth=[AUTH_TOKEN])` I get the `response: "Error=InvalidRegistration".`

There is no reason for this not to work. And yes, I have tried every solution available here in stack overflow, but remained unsuccessful. Here is my main code for my server side:

```
 WebRequest theRequest;
            HttpWebResponse theResponse;
            ArrayList theQueryData;

            theRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");                
            theRequest.Method = "POST";
            theQueryData = new ArrayList();

            String [] test = new String[5];
            test[0] = "accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE";
            test[1] = "Email=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
            test[2] = "Passwd=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
            test[3] = "Source=Domokun";
            test[4] = "service=ac2dm";

            // Set the encoding type
            theRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            // Build a string containing all the parameters
            string Parameters = String.Join("&", (String[])test);
            theRequest.ContentLength = Parameters.Length;

            // We write the parameters into the request
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(theRequest.GetRequestStream());
            sw.Write(Parameters);
            sw.Close();

            // Execute the query
            theResponse = (HttpWebResponse)theRequest.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(theResponse.GetResponseStream());
            String value = sr.ReadToEnd();
            String token = ParseForAuthTokenKey(value);
            String value2 = "";

            if (value != null)
            {
                WebRequest theRequest2;
                HttpWebResponse theResponse2;
                ArrayList theQueryData2;

                theRequest2 = WebRequest.Create("http://android.clients.google.com/c2dm/send");
                theRequest2.Method = "POST";


                theQueryData2 = new ArrayList();

                String[] test2 = new String[4];
                test[0] = "registration_id=" + registerid;
                test[1] = "collapse_key=0";
                test[2] = "data.payload=Jannik was hier"; 
                test[3] = "delay_while_idle=0";

                // Set the encoding type
                theRequest2.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";


                // Build a string containing all the parameters
                string Parameters2 = String.Join("&", (String[])test2);
                theRequest2.ContentLength = Parameters2.Length;
                theRequest2.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "GoogleLogin auth=" + token);


                // We write the parameters into the request
                StreamWriter sw2 = new StreamWriter(theRequest2.GetRequestStream());

                sw2.Write(Parameters2);
                sw2.Close();

                // Execute the query
                theResponse2 = (HttpWebResponse)theRequest2.GetResponse();
                StreamReader sr2= new StreamReader(theResponse2.GetResponseStream());
                value2 = sr2.ReadToEnd();
```

---

```
 public static bool RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private static string ParseForAuthTokenKey(string webResponse)
    {
        string tokenKey = String.Empty;
        if (webResponse.Contains(AuthTokenHeader))
        {
            tokenKey = webResponse.Substring(webResponse.IndexOf(AuthTokenHeader) + AuthTokenHeader.Length);
            if (tokenKey.Contains(Environment.NewLine))
            {
                tokenKey.Substring(0, tokenKey.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine));
            }
        }
        return tokenKey.Trim();
    }
```

---

All I can think is that my C2DM account isn't registered correctly. Could this be it? Or are there an error in my code that I'm missing?

Comment: Found the solution. My encoding wasn't perfect.

Comment: I am having an identical problem. Could you please elaborate on "Found the solution. My encoding wasn't perfect".

Comment: Yes, please post your solution below so we can get this off the unanswered list. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I've found the solution.

```
string requestBody = string.Format("registration_id={0}&collapse_key{1}&data.key=value",
                                    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(registrationId), "collapse");
string responseBody = null;

WebHeaderCollection requestHeaders = new WebHeaderCollection();
WebHeaderCollection responseHeaders = null;

requestHeaders.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, string.Format("GoogleLogin auth={0}", authToken));


httpClient.DoPostWithHeaders(c2dmPushUrl,
                  requestBody,
                  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                  out responseBody,
                  out responseHeaders,
                  requestHeaders);

public bool DoPostWithHeaders(string url, 
                              string requestBody, 
                              string contextType,
                          out string responseBody,
                          out WebHeaderCollection responseHeaders,
                              WebHeaderCollection requestHeaders = null)
{
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    // FIRST SET REQUEST HEADERS

    httpWebRequest.Headers = requestHeaders;
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

    // THEN SET CONTENT TYPE - THE ORDER IS IMPORTANT

    httpWebRequest.ContentType = contextType; 
    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(requestBody);
    httpWebRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

    stream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

    ....
    ....
    ....
}
```